# ngsw - angular service worker 504 error for document in Offline mode

Tags: angular, service-worker, angular-service-worker, angular-pwa, ngsw-config

Am using a angular application where i planned to use the angular /pwa ( ngsw ) for integration and when am loading service worker porperly registerd and i can see items in CacheStorage.  But when am going offline am getting an error. I now this is a long question but any help is realy appreciated.

I read many thread , To update scope i did that. adding webmanifest to MIME type now eveything is working in when browser is online only if i go offline document is not loading below error.

[image]

When am online below are the item i can see all loading from Service worker

[image]
[image]
[image]

below are my configuration am using angular 10

[image]

and below is my webmanifest i updated the scope to "." after reading some thread that if we are putting this in subfolder of IIS we need to change the scope.

[image]

i haven't changed anything in ngsw.json

[image]
only think we are doing differnt in this angular project is putting the app inside the project folder as we have different project

[image]